# How to efficiently keep track of largest user inputted value?

Tags: python, variables, max

I need to find the largest number the user input but I can not define the largest as a number, like I defined "largest = -9999999", any suggestions?
the "clargest" is to count how many time the largest number occurs

```
largest = -9999999

clargest = 0

while num != 0 :
    num = input("Enter your number or type 0 to end: ")
    if (num[0] == "-" and num[1:].isdigit()) or num.isdigit():
        num = int(num)
        if num != 0:
            if num > largest:
                clargest = 1
            elif num == largest:
                clargest = clargest + 1
            largest = max(largest,num)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can not define the largest as a number"? Do you mean you can't arbitrarily declare "The biggest number the user input was 12", or do you mean you have to represent it as some sort of non-numeric data type, or what?

Comment: It looks like what you have does pretty close to what you want. You didn't initialize `num`, and your input validation is a bit wonky, but the `largest` and `clargest` logic seems okay.

Comment: I can not say largest = -999 because what if the user inputs -9999

Comment: It sounds like you want the largest possible int supported by Python, which is [`sys.maxint`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.maxint).

Comment: @CoreyWu: No, that's not what the OP needs (and since ints overflow to longs, it's not that useful these days).

Comment: @CoreyWu did not work! :/

Comment: @user3311946 Did you add `import sys`?

Answer (score 2):

You can start with the mathematically meaningful `largest = float('-inf')`, since the user is only allowed to enter (signed) integer numbers.

Side note: there is a much simpler way of writing your loop:

```
while num != 0 :
    num = input("Enter your number or type 0 to end: ")
    if (num[0] == "-" and num[1:].isdigit()) or num.isdigit():
        num = int(num)
        if num != 0:
    # ... keep track of largest
```

would be simpler as:

```
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input("Enter..."))
    except ValueError:
        continue
    if num == 0:
        break
    # ... keep track of largest
```

This use the recommended "it's better to ask forgiveness than permission" (`try`). It also removes the repetition of `num != 0`. The test of "is this is number" is also more obvious. The need to have num be both a string and a number is also removed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options. Here are two of them:

Option 1:
Keep a list of all the numbers that the user input, sort it, and take the last one.

Option 2:
(I think this is what you're trying to do)
Keep track of the largest number that has been entered so far. Instead of defining largest as a large, negative number just keep around a boolean value that says if the input is the first number. The first number entered by the user is always the largest. For you, specifically, when `clargest` is 0 you can set `largest` to the user input.

Comment: Option 3: input something before the loop

Comment: No need for a boolean, you can use the fact that `clargest==0` can only happen for the first number.

Comment: Sort? Why sort? If you're keeping a list, `largest = max(l); clargest = l.count(largest)`.

Comment: @MarkRansom I was speaking in generalities, hence the last sentence.

Comment: @user2357112 That's an alternative to what you've done.

Comment: The first method is generally uselessly expensive. The second method is unnecessarily complicated (using `float('-inf')`) is way more direct and is generally more efficient than testing whether we're reading the first number at each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @EOL `clargest` is a counter of how many times the `largest` has been incremented, so it is always legal to do `largest = num` when `clargest` is 0, regardless of the sign of the input.

Comment: @maxywb: You're completely right, my bad, sorry. That's why I always insist that my students use explicit variable names (`count_largest`). :)